# Вопрос по php циклу

Tags: php

Генерирую портфолио на сайте, блоки которые генерируются должны по очереди иметь класс is-left is-right, т.е. каждый второй блок имеет класс is-right. Генерируется всё через while. Как это реализовать?

Comment: вести в цикле переменную вроде `$x=1-$x` она будет принимать значения то 0 то 1. на нее ориентироваться. Или, если есть переменная с номером текущей строки, брать ее остаток от деления на 2

Comment: @oskar [см.пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/072efa031eddd516dabdcfbcaa92cbf7381af785)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос закрыт.